# Where do i get the most updated version of the matplotlibrc file?

Tags: matplotlib

Where do i get the most updated version of the matplotlibrc file ?
How do i install other modules like xmlstore , NavigationWx2 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `matplotlibrc` usually resides in `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`. Unless you are using the system default, which depends on where your python distribution is installed. Relative to site-packages, it should be in `matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc`.

It doesn't make sense to get the 'most updated version'. You should use the version that came with your installation, otherwise it may refer to different settings that are not implemented.

About "xmlstore" and "NavigationWx2", I don't know what they are. They are not matplotlib components nor are listed on [PyPI](http://pypi.python.org).